# No longer unable to retrieve data from QIODevice after calling readAll(). Buffer flushed?

Tags: c++, qt, buffer, flush

I've just noticed something when using `QNetworkReply` that I was unable to find the slightest hint in the [Qt documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#readAll) for `QIODevice::readAll()` (which the `QNetworkReply` inherits this method from).

Here is what the documentation states:

> **Reads all remaining data** from the device, and **returns it as a byte**
>   **array**.
>
> This function has no way of reporting errors; returning an **empty**
>   QByteArray can mean either that **no data** was currently available for
>   reading, **or** that an **error occurred**.

Let's say I have the following connection:

```
connect(this->reply, &QIODevice::readyRead, this, &MyApp::readyReadRequest);
```

Ths `readyReadRequest()` slot looks like this:

```
void MyApp::readyReadRequest()
{
    LOG(INFO) << "Received data from \"" << this->url.toString() << "\"";
    LOG(INFO) << "Data contents:\n" << QString(this->reply->readAll());
    this->bufferReply = this->reply->readAll();
}
```

The surprise came after I called `this->bufferReply` (which a `QByteArray` class member of `MyApp`). I passed it to a `QXmlStreamReader` and did:

```
while (!reader.atEnd())
{
    LOG(DEBUG) << "Reading next XML element";
    reader.readNext();
    LOG(DEBUG) << reader.tokenString();
}
if (reader.hasError())
{
    LOG(ERROR) << "Encountered error while parsing XML data:" << reader.errorString();
}
```

Imagine my surprise when I got the following output:

> 2017-10-17 16:12:18,591 DEBUG [default] [void MyApp::processReply()][...] Reading next XML element
>
> 2017-10-17 16:12:18,591 DEBUG [default] [void MyApp::processReply()] [...] Invalid
>
> 2017-10-17 16:12:18,591 ERROR [default] Encountered error while parsing XML data: Premature end of document

Through debugging I got that my `bufferReply` at this point is empty. I looked in the docs again but couldn't find anything that hints removing the data from the device (in my case the network reply) after reading it all.

Removing the line where I print the byte array or simply moving it after `this->bufferReply = this->reply->readAll();` and then printing the contents of the class member fixed the issue:

```
void MyApp::readyReadRequest()
{
    LOG(INFO) << "Received data from \"" << this->url.toString() << "\"";
    this->bufferReply = this->reply->readAll();
    LOG(INFO) << "Data contents:\n" << QString(this->bufferReply);
}
```

However I would like to know if I'm doing something wrong or is the documentation indeed incomplete.

Since `readAll()` doesn't report errors or that data is not available at the given point in time returning an empty byte array is the only thing that hints towards the fact that something didn't work as intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. When you call `QIODevice::readAll()` 2 times, it is normal that the 2nd time you get nothing. Everything has been read, there is nothing more to be read.

This behavior is standard in IO read functions: each call to a read() function returns the next piece of data. Since `readAll()` reads to the end, further calls return nothing.

However, this does not necessarily means that the data has been flushed. For instance when you read a file, it just moves a "cursor" around and you can go back to the start of the file with `QIODevice::seek(0)`. For `QNetworkReply`, I'd guess that the data is just discarded.

Comment: Thanks. Although it's typical it would be nice to give heads up in the documentation. ;)

Comment: @rbaleksandar You can fill a request on https://bugreports.qt.io/ if you feel it can be improved